# Reversed UV image

Tags: uv

I am trying to add a texture to a simple mesh with a front and back side. I have mapped several similar meshes without problems but this one is stumping me. For some reason the "back" texture is reversed and I cannot get it corrected.
I have tried reversing UV's, flipping normals, and UV unwrapping from both the front and back view (not sure if that does anything). I tried all combinations of the aforementioned, to no avail. Any clue as to what I'm missing here?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The render behaves the same as viewing the material in the viewport. I've uploaded the node screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the issue is that you are using an object that has no thickness and the front and back faces are the same.

You can use the backfacing information of the geometry node to assign different textures to the front and back of the object.

To flip the texture on the back side use a Vector>Mapping node, and set the backface's scale on the X axis to -1

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after a closer look of my texture image I realized that I created it incorrectly. Thus I'd never get the texture to work correct (smacks forehead).